# Como modificar um conteúdo com InnerHTML de um array utilizando querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist

Olá, tudo bem? Sou iniciante em JS e estou tentando modificar o innerHTML de alguns botões utilizando o querySelectorAll. Eu gostaria que quando clicasse no botão, o html modificasse o texto 'Alugar filme' para 'Devolver filme'. Estou tentando utilizar o botao.innerHTML = ('Devolver filme') (linha 6) porém não esta dando certo. Tem alguma sintaxe usada nesse caso?

```
var botao = document.querySelectorAll('.dashboard__item__button'); // 3 botões 

for (var i = 0; i < botao.length; i++)
  botao[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert('Funcionou!') // teste para ver se o click está funcionando.
    //botao.innerHTML = ('Devolver filme')
    });
```

Comment: se o alert está sendo disparado, substituir botao.innerHTML para botao[i].innerHTML deve funcionar. Substituir o callback de addEventListener por algo como (e) => e.currentTarget.textContent = 'Devolver filme', também faria sentido.

Comment: @VanderSantos isso não vai funcionar, pq dentro da função não exite o "botao[i]"

Comment: dentro da função, pode usar `this.innerHTML = 'Devolver filme'` por exemplo. Nesse caso o `this` representa o botão que foi clicado

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigada pela ajuda! Era somente um ''this'' pro meu código funcionar hehe

Comment: Na realidade em Javascript, as funções tem acesso às variáveis do seu ambiente externo. E é exatamente por essa razão que clojures são possíveis em JS. De todo o modo, a sua soluçaõ com this é interessante.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Se `i` fosse declarado com `let`, `botão[i]` existiria via closure dentro do listener.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que seja possível resolver isso de duas maneiras:

1. **Usando o `this` antes de innerHTML**. Em JavaScript, this se refere imediatamente ao objeto acima de onde é chamado. Se a função for chamada no contexto de um objeto (ou seja, uma função de método), this se refere ao objeto que possui a função.

```
var botoes = document.querySelectorAll('.dashboard__item__button'); 
for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
  botoes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'Devolver filme';
  });
}
```

2. **Usando `closure` com `IIFE`**. Mas é bem mais complicado e fica um pouco mais difícil de ler.

```
var botoes = document.querySelectorAll('.dashboard__item__button'); 

for (var i = 0; i < botoes.length; i++) {
  (function(index) { // Usamos uma função closure para capturar o valor atual de i
    botoes[index].addEventListener("click", 
        function() {
            botoes[index].innerHTML = 'Devolver filme';
        });
  })(i); // Passamos o valor de i para a função closure como parametro da IIFE
}
```

**IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**: é uma função JavaScript que é declarada e executada imediatamente.

```
(function() {
    // codigo da função
})();
```

**Closure**: ocorre quando uma função consegue acessar o escopo do ambiente lexico ao seu redor (escopo da função externa ou escopo global). Closures sempre acontecem em JS com todas as funções.